# Problem importing qgis.core inside docker container

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo, osgeo4w

I'm trying to use QGIS libraries in docker container. When I try import qgis.core I get this error, really I can't figure out what is the cause.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/core/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: No module named _core
```

I've added proper paths to PATH environment.

```
sys.path.append("/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins")
sys.path.append("/usr/share/qgis/python")
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")
```

and this is my PATH

`/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins:/usr/share/qgis/python:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:`